# Get word between two numbers java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the name word between the first id and before the second number.
I want to do this in Java Regex.

e.g. Car Care or Car Electronics & Accessories

```
#   Name    Id  Child nodes
1   Car Care    15718271    Browse 

2   Car Electronics & Accessories   2230642011  Browse

3   Exterior Accessories    15857511    Browse
```

I tried splitting the line with .split(" ")[1] but then it splits the words with spaces. Only gives one word within a phrase e.g. Car

Comment: Please add to the question what you have tried that did not work out.

Comment: What if the business name includes numbers? Because such business exist. If this is truly your input file and the 'area' between e.g. the '1', the 'Car Care' and '15718271', then the file is unparseable. I bet those are tabs in between though, not spaces. In which case this is standard CSV and you should use a CSV parser to read this. or split on tabs if you insist on handrolling a CSV library (don't do that).

Comment: You're right about them being tabs and not spaces. I tried splitting by tabs and it worked. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:`^\d*[a-zA-Z &+-]*(\d*)[a-zA-Z ]*`
In the match '(\d*)' you will find the wished number.
If the strings before and after the number have special characters add them to the appropiate [] sections.
Explaination: '^' says start from the beginning, '\d*' take the first digit one or multiple times, [a-zA-Z &+-] take a string with these characters, (\d*) specifies the wished number, [a-zA-Z ] again takes a string after the number. Use a regex editor for trying this out.

Comment: This seems to just match the first number when I try match it.

Comment: You are right, this happens when someone like me does NOT properly read your question. I am sorry. I thought you want to match the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?m)^\d+\s+(.*?)\s+\d{6,}\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JeNJAC/2). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline option
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d{6,}` - six or more digits
- `\s`  - a whitespace.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/An21XL):

```java
String s = "#   Name    Id  Child nodes\n1   Car Care    15718271    Browse \n2   Car Electronics & Accessories   2230642011  Browse\n3   Exterior Accessories    15857511    Browse";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\d+\\s+(.*?)\\s+\\d{6,}\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
Car Care
Car Electronics & Accessories
Exterior Accessories
```

Comment: Hi separating with split tab worked thanks